# Ruby on Rails has_many :through STI foreign key issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

I have a user class from the Devise gem.

I have a admin_account class that is inherited from user using STI.
I have a admin_task class.
I have a admin_task_assignment class.

I am getting a foreign key error while trying to create an admin task assignment through the rails console.

`t = AdminTaskAssignment.create(admin_account_id: 1, admin_task_id: 1)`

I am searching for both AdminAccount.find(1) and for AdminTask.find(1) to find records that exist. But I get:

`SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey) FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (SQLite3::ConstraintException)`

```
class AdminAccount < User 
    has_many :admin_task_assignments,  foreign_key: 'admin_account_id'
    has_many :admin_tasks, through: :admin_task_assignments
end

class AdminTask < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :admin_task_assignments, foreign_key: 'admin_task_id'
    has_many :admin_accounts, through: :admin_task_assignments
    belongs_to :client
end

class AdminTaskAssignment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :admin_account, foreign_key: 'admin_account_id'
    belongs_to :admin_task, foreign_key: 'admin_task_id'
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :admin_tasks
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :type, :string
  validates :email, uniqueness: true

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

end
```

```
create_table "admin_accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "admin_task_assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "admin_account_id", null: false
    t.integer "admin_task_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["admin_account_id"], name: "index_admin_task_assignments_on_admin_account_id"
    t.index ["admin_task_id"], name: "index_admin_task_assignments_on_admin_task_id"
end

create_table "admin_tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "client_id", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.string "task_type"
    t.index ["client_id"], name: "index_admin_tasks_on_client_id"
end
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "type"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

add_foreign_key "admin_task_assignments", "admin_accounts"
add_foreign_key "admin_task_assignments", "admin_tasks"
add_foreign_key "admin_tasks", "clients"
```

Comment: Where's the user table? if you are doing STI you would not have a an admin_accounts table. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

Comment: Kill the admin_accounts table and set all your task foreign keys to the user table, at which point you will probably realize that you are not buying anything with the STI approach.

Comment: @dbugger what do you mean by that? If my ultimate goal is to add another type of user that also has its own type of task, is there a better approach to use? I figured if they were both inherited from the user class, all of the devise stuff would come through and then I could setup specific associations for each type of user.

Comment: then do that -- but you've already left the path of STI by adding the admin_accounts table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off just get rid of all the cruft from your models:

- Emails validations are already handled by Devise::Validatable
- You do not need to define attributes that exist in the schema.
- You do not need to configure the foreign key option if it can be derived from the name of the assocation and you don't win anything by being overly explicit.

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end

class AdminAccount < User
  has_many :admin_task_assignments
  has_many :admin_tasks, 
    through: :admin_task_assignments
end

class AdminTaskAssignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :admin_account 
  belongs_to :admin_task
end

class AdminTask < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :admin_task_assignments
  has_many :admin_accounts, 
    through: :admin_task_assignments
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Then lets address the database schema.

- You do not need or want the `admin_accounts` table if you're using Single Table Inheritance. ActiveRecord won't even use it since AdminAccount inherits from User. Drop it.
- You need to setup the foreign keys properly so that they point to the `users` table.

If you haven't merged/pushed these schema changes the easiest way to rectify this is to just rollback to before you created the `admin_accounts` table and fix/delete the migrations:

```
class CreateAdminTaskAssignments < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :admin_task_assignments do |t|
      t.belongs_to :admin_account, 
        null: false, 
        foreign_key: { to_table: :users } # this is super important
      t.belongs_to :admin_task, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
      # optional -- add a unique index to ensure that the same task can't be assigned multiple times
      # t.index [:admin_account_id, :admin_task_id], unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

And delete the migration that creates the `admin_accounts` table. Re-run the migrations and Bob's you're uncle. Since you're dropping the tables you won't have to deal with having a bunch of orphaned records with junk data.

If you need to fix this in place you would need to remove the foreign key and replace it with the correct one:

```
class FixTaskAssignmentsForeignKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    remove_foreign_key :admin_tasks, :admin_accounts
    add_foreign_key :admin_tasks, :users, 
     column: :admin_account_id
  end
end
```

Note that if you have added a bunch of data to your app already it might already have garbage values in the `admin_account_id` column that are actually the ids from your defunct admin_accounts table and not the user id. You may need to truncate the table.

And then you can drop the `admin_accounts` table since there is no longer a foreign key that references it:

```
class DropAdminAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    drop_table :admin_accounts do |t|
      t.timestamps 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for this! This makes a lot more sense. One more quick question..

For this part

`add_foreign_key :admin_tasks, :users, column: :admin_task_id`

can you explain what this is doing cause it doesnt seem to make sense to me. Why wouldnt this foreign key be declared the same way as it was for admin_task_assignment with {to_table :users} ? Also wouldnt it be the admin_account_id and not admin_task_id?

Comment: Oops. That was a copy paste error - it should be `add_foreign_key :admin_tasks, :users, column: :admin_account_id`.

Comment: I was able to get this working without that part. I am new to rails, sorry if this is a basic question, but I thought the foreign keys were always in the table that had the belongs_to part relationship. Is it necessary to add a foreign key in the task table that points to the admin account? I figured I could get that data through the task_assignment.

Comment: Ah, you're right here again - `add_foreign_key :admin_task_assignments, :users, column: :admin_account_id`. Third times the charm.